# How do you judge graphics cards as "greater" when evaluating system requirements?

Tags: graphics-card, compatibility, specifications, requirements, oculus-rift

The [Oculus Video](https://www.oculus.com/experiences/rift/926562347437041/) app for the Oculus Rift VR headset has the following recommended system requirements for your PC:

> **Recommended Processor** 
>   Intel i5-4590 equivalent or greater 
>   **Recommended Graphics Card** 
>   NVIDIA GTX 970 / AMD R9 290 equivalent or greater

Now I'm getting a new PC, [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01NBL8BER) by CyberPowerPC, and I'd like to know if it meets these requirements.  It has an "AMD Radeon RX 480 4GB Video Card".  So my question is, how do I determine whether this graphics card is "equivalent or greater" than the NVIDIA GTX 970 and the AMD R9 290?

EDIT: The close reason says "Instead of asking what to buy, try asking how to find out what suits your needs." I think my question meets that criterion.  I didn't ask for a shopping recommendation, I just asked how do I evaluate whether the graphics card I was looking at meets certain system requirements or not.  In any case, the question was satisfactorily answered, so I don't need help anymore, but I think it should remain open so others can benefit from it.

Comment: Instead of including commentary on the reason you don't agree with the close reason, you should just address the close reason, and improve the quality of your question.  So please remove your commentary from your question.

Comment: @Ramhound I explained why I thought the closure was wrong, and the community agreed with me and already reopened my question.

Comment: Which is the reason you should remove the commentary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benchmarks, and finding out which cards are newer.

The easiest way to evaluate whether one thing is better than another is by using benchmarks.

One good site is [VideocardBenchmark.net](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/high_end_gpus.html) where performance figures can give you a rough idea of whether one card performs better than another.

The other factor is how old the card is. Newer cards support newer features but an older card may still be higher on the benchmark but not support the same features required by your program such as DirectX 12.

So you are looking for a card on that benchmark list that is higher and newer than a GTX 970, or higher and newer than an R9 290. They are both pretty high end cards.

That website also lets you compare cards thusly: http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/compare.php?cmp%5B%5D=2719&cmp%5B%5D=3533

[image]

As you can see the RX480 performs *slightly* better than the R9 290, is newer, supports the same or better features and has a significantly lower power draw which is probably the main benefit.

That card would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect, but I find the Tom's Hardware graphics card hierarchy charts are a reasonably simple place to start when trying to determine if one card is better or worse than another.

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/gpu-hierarchy,review-33383.html